# Exibição do nome na Diagonal (Cima para Baixo)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho que ler um nome e exibi-lo na diagonal, ou seja, de cima para baixo.

Porém não estou conseguindo desenvolver a lógica correta, consegui chegar a isto:

```
nome = input('Digite o seu nome: ')
tamanho = len(nome)

for nome in range(tamanho):
    print(nome)
```

Mas ele retorna apenas a contagem do tamanho da String, e quero que no lugar da contagem exiba a respectiva letra do nome que o usuário digitou.

Comment: Você pode me explicar melhor por favor? voce quer que o usuario digite um numero e aparece a letra que corresponde a esse numero?

Answer (score 4):

A função `range(n)` irá gerar uma sequência de números inteiros [0, n[, o que não é muito útil para você nesse caso. Se entendi bem, você precisa imprimir o nome informado na "diagonal", algo como:

```
>>> Insira seu nome: anderson
a
 n
  d
   e
    r
     s
      o
       n
```

Ou seja, você incrementa o número de espaços em branco antes de cada letra. A primeira letra, no índice 0, possui zeros espaços; a segunda, no índice 1, possui um espaço; assim sucessivamente. Então, para você obter a letra e seu respectivo índice dentro do nome você deve usar a função `enumerate`:

```
nome = input('Insira seu nome:')

for indice, letra in enumerate(nome):
    print(' ' * indice + letra)
```

E você terá a apresentação do nome como exemplificado.

Comment: Bom vendo a sua solução consegui fazer de uma forma mais simples, porem nao entendi a parte do '   print(' ' * indice + letra)   '

Comment: esse foi meu codigo        nome = input('Digite o seu nome: ')
                                        for c in nome:
                                               print(c)

Comment: @GiovanniManganotti E onde entra o "diagonal" aí?

Comment: ele vai imprimir uma letra a cada laço, assim o nome fica na diagonal, executa ele pra tu ve, usa esse compilador online ---> https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler